# Real part of $(1+2i)^n$

Tags: complex-numbers

Is it true that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n\ge 2$ we have
$$|\textrm{Re}((1+2i)^n)|>1?$$

I do know  de Moivre's Theorem.

I do not know how to show that $|\sqrt{5}^n\cos(n\arccos\left ( \frac{1}{5} \right ))|>1$ because the value $\cos(n\arccos\left ( \frac{1}{5} \right ))$ can become (theoretically) arbitrarily small.

Comment: Did you try $n=2$?

Comment: I corrected my question.

Comment: $1+2i=\sqrt{5}e^{i\arctan(2)}$, hence $$(1+2i)^n=\sqrt{5}^n\cdot{e^{in\arctan(2)}}=\sqrt{5}\cos(n\arctan(2))+\sqrt{5}i \sin(n\arctan(2))$$ Can you continue?

Comment: Maybe this is the wrong tack but by the binomial theorem wont the real part always be an integer.  So suffices other options are the real part can't be 0 or +/- 1.  Is that doable?

Comment: The real part is always an integer $\equiv1\pmod4$, so, following fleablood's suggestion, it suffices to exclude the possibility that it is equal to $1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I know this.

Comment: This question is related to the one at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697058/on-equations-m21-5n

Comment: Furthermore, for the real part to be equal to $1$, it has to be congruent to $1$ w.r.t. any modulus $m$. With $m=5$ we get that $n$ has to be $\equiv1\pmod4$. With $m=13$ we get that $n$ has to be $\equiv0,1\pmod{12}$. Putting those two together leaves the possibility $n\equiv1\pmod{12}$. Doesn't look very useful :-(

Comment: I forgot the name of the method, but there are some $p$-adics methods that can sometimes solve this kind of problems.

Comment: Yet another useless equivalent formulation. Define the sequence $(G_n)$ by declaring $G_0=G_1=1$, $G_{n+2}=2G_{n+1}-5G_n$ for all $n\ge0$. Prove that $G_n\neq1$ for all $n>1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: looking mod $4$, $11$, and $25$ *does* give a full result.

Comment: @BarryCipra: thanks for pointing that out! I have added an answer there using my answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Recursion for $\boldsymbol{r_n=\mathrm{Re}\!\left((1+2i)^n\right)}$**

Both $1+2i$ and $1-2i$ satisfy the equation $z^2-2z+5=0$. Therefore, the real part of $(1+2i)^n$
$$
r_n=\frac{(1+2i)^n+(1-2i)^n}2
$$
satisfies
$$
r_n=2r_{n-1}-5r_{n-2}
$$

---

**mod $\boldsymbol{4}$**

Since $r_0=r_1=1$, we have that $r_n\equiv1\pmod{4}$ for all $n$.

Therefore, if $\left|r_n\right|\le1$, we must have $r_n=1$.

---

**mod $\boldsymbol{25}$**

Compute the first $24$ terms:
$$
\small r_n=1,1,\underbrace{22,14,18,16,17,4,23,\overset{\normalsize r_9}{1},12,19,3,11,7,9,8,21,2,24,13,6}_{\text{period of $20$}},22,14,\dots\pmod{25}
$$
This means that if $n\ge2$ and $r_n=1$, we must have $n\equiv9\pmod{20}$.

---

**mod $\boldsymbol{11}$**

Since $(1+2i)^3=-11-2i\equiv9i\pmod{11}$, [Little Fermat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem) says
$$
(1+2i)^{60}\equiv(9i)^{20}=81^{10}\equiv1\pmod{11}
$$

Therefore, $r_n\pmod{11}$ repeats every $60$ terms. However,
$$
\begin{align}
r_9&\equiv0\pmod{11}\\
r_{29}&\equiv2\pmod{11}\\
r_{49}&\equiv9\pmod{11}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, if $n\equiv9\pmod{20}$, $r_n\not\equiv1\pmod{11}$.

---

**Conclusion**

$\left|r_n\right|\gt1$ for $n\ge2$.

Comment: When I first read the question, I thought it said $\ge1$. I didn't get back for quite a while before I could revisit my answer. I modified it with a better partial answer. Now, the answer is complete. Perhaps the downvotes can be removed.

Comment: Nice solution! If $|r_n|\le 1$ we must have $r_n=1$ or $r_n=-1$. And we have to check the case $r_n = 24 \pmod {25}$ too, but your method also works well for it.

Comment: @Andrey: True, but neither $r_n=-1$ nor $r_n=0$ are allowed because $r_n\equiv1\pmod4$.

Answer (score 4):

Because $1+2i$ has integer real and imaginary parts, $\text{Re}((1+2i)^n)$ is always an integer.  It's also easy to see that it is always odd.  So the real question is, can it be $\pm 1$?

If $\theta = \arctan(2)$, $\text{Re}((1+2i)^n) = 5^{n/2} \cos(n\theta)$.  For this to be $\pm 1$ requires $|n \theta - k \pi/2| < 2\cdot 5^{-n/2}$ for some odd integer $k$.  That means that 
$\pi/\theta$, which we know is an irrational number, is very closely
approximated by a rational.  That's very unlikely to be the case, but I don't know of any way to prove it.  There are lower bounds on how closely $\pi$ can be approximated by rationals, but I'm not aware of anything similar for $\pi/\theta$.

Comment: I had this idea, but I hoped that the situation may not be so sad...

Answer (score 4):

$a_{2n} = Re((1+2i)^{2n}) = Re((-3+4i)^n) = Re((1+4(-1+i))^n)$

Applying the Binomial expansion we get $(1+4(-1+i))^n$ as a series that converges $2$-adically :

$(1+4(-1+i))^n = 1 + 4(-1+i)\binom n1 -32i \binom n2 + \ldots + 4^k(-1+i)^k\binom nk + \ldots$

Since $v_2(4^k/k!) \ge k \to \infty$, this gives a $2$-adic power series

$(1+4(-1+i))^n = 1 + a_1 n + a_2 n^2 + \ldots$ where $a_k \in 2^k \Bbb Z_{(2)}[i]$

Taking the real part we get $a_{2n} = 1 + b_1 n + b_2 n^2 + \dots$

Computing the first few coefficients mod $8$, we get $b_1 = 4 \pmod 8$ and $b_n = 0 \pmod 8$ for $n > 1$, which shows that the map $n \mapsto a_{2n}$, when extended continuously to $\Bbb Z_{(2)}$, is a bijection from $\Bbb Z_{(2)}$ to $1+4\Bbb Z_{(2)}$. So it takes the value $1$ exactly once, at $n=0$.

For $a_{2n+1}$ the same thing works : $(1+2i)^{2n+1} = (1+2i)^{2n}(1+2i)$, so we just multiply each $a_k$ by $(1+2i)$ before taking real parts. Again we end up on $a_{2n+1} = 1 + 4n \pmod 8$, so it is again a bijection from $\Bbb Z_{(2)}$ to $1+4\Bbb Z_{(2)}$, it takes the value $1$ exactly once, at $n=0$.

You can be a bit more precise and show that $v_2(a_{2n} - a_{2m}) = v_2(a_{2n+1} - a_{2m+1}) = v_2(4(n-m)) = 2+v_2(n-m)$

This also implies that $(a_n)$ can only take a particular value at most twice, and so $|a_n| \to \infty$.

Comment: Is this basically [Skolem-Mahler-Lech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Mahler%E2%80%93Lech_theorem)?

Comment: yes, that's their idea.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

All parts are integer.

Let $|\Re(1+2i)^n|=1=5^{n/2}|\cos(n\alpha)|$, with $\alpha=\arctan(2)$.

Then we must have $|\Im(1+2i)^n|=5^{n/2}|\sin(n\alpha)|=5^{n/2}\sqrt{1-5^{-n}}=\sqrt{5^n-1}\in\mathbb N$, i.e. $5^n-1$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Ah!  So [Mihailescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) finishes the job!

Comment: @RobertIsrael: absolutely !

Comment: Heavy artillery was used :)

Comment: @Andrey: fortunately, the Fermat-Wiles theorem was avoided.